# laravel sorting in view

Tags: php, sorting, laravel, laravel-4

i'm using laravel 4.1 and i am stuck in a repeatitive task.
to sort the index of people i do this:

```
$sort = (!is_null(Input::get('sort')) ? Input::get('sort') : 'lastname'); 
//with 'lastname' being the default column to sort on.
$order = (!is_null(Input::get('order')) ? Input::get('order') : 'asc');
//'desc' is the default sort order.
$people = $people->orderBy($sort, $order);
$people = $people->paginate(20);
return View::make('people.index', array('people' => $people, 'sort' => $sort, 'order' => $order));
```

in the view self i create the links to sort with this snippet, which also works fine

```
<th>{{link_to_route(Route::currentRouteName(),'Lastname', array('sort' => 'lastname'))}}
@if ($order != 'asc')
  <a href="{{URL::route(Route::currentRouteName(), array('sort' => $sort, 'order' => 'asc'))}}">
    <i class="fa fa-sort-asc "></i>
  </a>
@else
  <a href="{{URL::route(Route::currentRouteName(), array('sort' => $sort, 'order' => 'desc'))}}">
    <i class="fa fa-sort-desc "></i>
  </a>
@endif</th>
```

The problem i have is tha i want to sort multiple columns. My question is: Do i have to copy the down part in every head column? or can i put the part somewhere so i can use it with a simplier call ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a form macro http://laravel.com/docs/html#custom-macros :

```
// somewhere, e.g. in app/start/global.php:
Form::macro('headColumn', function($sort, $order = 'asc')
{
    $url = URL::route(Route::currentRouteName(), array('sort' => $sort, 'order' => $order));
    return '<a href="'.$url.'">
    <i class="fa fa-sort-desc "></i>
  </a>';
});
```

Then inside the view:

```
<th>
{{ link_to_route(Route::currentRouteName(),'Lastname', array('sort' => 'lastname')) }}
@if ($order != 'asc')
  {{ Form::headColumn($sort) }}
@else
  {{ Form::headColumn($sort, 'desc') }}
@endif
</th>
```

(I did not test this but I think the idea should be clear.)